# Linux console output on multiple UARTs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

My embedded board has 2 UARTs. I want to have console output on both the UARTs.

In *kernel/Documentation/console/console.txt* it's mentioned that:

> you can only define one console per device type (serial, video).

Does this mean I can use only one UART as console? Or, is it possible to redirect the console output to both of these UARTs?

Comment: One would be preferred console. Otherwise, `console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=ttyS1,57600n8` or alike. http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/admin-guide/serial-console.rst

Comment: @0andriy Correct. Repost your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to achieve that via adding consoles to the kernel command line.
For example,`console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=ttyS1,57600n8` will add two serial consoles (8250 driver assumed) on ports 0 and 1 (whatever it means on the platform in question). One of them will be so called *preferred*.

For the details, consult kernel documentation: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/admin-guide/serial-console.rst